# после fetch запроса ответ приходит, но объекте запроса пусто

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors, response

была проблема с fetch запросом на сервер express через vue cli, была ошибка с "cors", исправил, теперь запрос получаю, но я это вижу в networke инструмента разработчика [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в консоле пусто[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код:

```
methods: {
async getInfo () {
  const response = await fetch('https://ksjkfsjdbnfksjfksjf744.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/api/demo',
    { mode: 'no-cors' })
  const responseString = await response
  const responseObject = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseString))
  console.log(responseString)
  console.log(responseObject)
}
```

}

Comment: "no-cors" на фронте тут не поможет, Вам нужно настроить cors на сервере

Comment: В режиме `no-cors` ответ сервера в JS получить нельзя. Это явно запрещено спецификацией.

Comment: К Vue вопрос не имеет отношение.

Comment: `const responseString = await response` заменить на `const responseString = await response.json()`. А вот это `const responseObject = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseString))` - убрать.

Answer (score 0):

> после fetch запроса ответ приходит, но объекте запроса пусто

Если в ответ на запрос данные приходят - получить их можно вот таким образом.

```js
async function getInfo() {
  let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  response = await response.json()
  console.log(response)
}

getInfo()
```